# How can I import base64 image in JSON into core data binary via RESTkit 2.0 in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, json, base64, restkit

I have been using **importObjectsFromItemAtPath** from **RKManagedObjectImporter** (using RESTkit 2.0 framework) to import some data from a JSON file and put it into core data.  I want to put some small images in the JSON file.  I've converted these to base64 strings.  I know how to convert base64 strings into binary data to store in core data and how to retrieve that and create a UIImage but I don't know how to convert the base64 string into binary data using **importObjectsFromItemPath**

I'm currently using a workaround by just reading the JSON then manually converting the base64 string into binary data then storing it into core data, but I would prefer to use the RESTkit mapping method since I use that for all my other JSON files.  Anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: How are you reading the JSON in the workaround? Can you have a mapping to a temporary attribute on your model class and implementation in that setter method to do the conversion?

Comment: My workaround uses NSJSONSerialization to the JSON file into a dictionary then I loop thru the dic contents and add them as new entity objects into core data, but I'll convert the JSON base64 string into binary data just before that happens.  That isn't too much hassle 'cos I'm not using any relationships in this table.  I thought about reading into a temp string attribute then converting and putting into the binary attribute but that seemed more effort than my current workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an RKValueTransformer to do this for you. Basically, these are objects for mapping between native types and JSON responses (and vice versa).

Here's mine that does base64 strings (which could be from JSON) to NSData.

```
[RKValueTransformer.defaultValueTransformer
 insertValueTransformer:
 [RKBlockValueTransformer
  valueTransformerWithValidationBlock:^BOOL(__unsafe_unretained Class inputValueClass, __unsafe_unretained Class outputValueClass) {
      return [inputValueClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSString class]] && [outputValueClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSData class]];
  }
  transformationBlock:^BOOL(id inputValue, __autoreleasing id *outputValue, __unsafe_unretained Class outputClass, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
      RKValueTransformerTestInputValueClassIsSubclassOfClass(outputClass, [NSString class], error);
      RKValueTransformerTestOutputValueClassIsSubclassOfClass(outputClass, [NSData class], error);
      // If iOS7+
      //*outputValue = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString*)inputValue options:0];
      // If iOS6-
      *outputValue = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64Encoding:(NSString*)inputValue];
      return YES;
  }] atIndex:0];
```